# Make the media uploader accept flash files

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working with `WordPress` on a project and I need to allow the `WordPress` `Media-Uploader`.

I need to allow the upload of `flash` files since everytime I attempt to upload a flash file i get the following error: `Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.`

I tried to find within the doc but I couldnt find a place where it tell me how to allow flash files.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. To allow this you'll need to either change the core or install a plugin such as http://wordpress.org/plugins/mime-types-extended/.

There are other plugins here: http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=mime

Edit:

According to [this](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/tips-articles/quick-tip-add-extra-media-type-filters-to-the-wordpress-media-manager/) tutorial, you can infact define additional mimetypes easily.